# NodeJS/Electron: Is it possible to register "STRG+<" as a globalShortcut and how can I do this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to register `STRG+<` as a `globalShortcut` in my electron app.
It was possible to register this hotkey with autoit, so I don't think nodejs/electron can't.

Can you please help me?

The following hotkey is working: `CommandOrControl+X`

This is not working: `CommandOrControl+<`

In the internet I didn't find the corresponding keycode for Javascript.

```
const globalHotkey = globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+X', () => {
    console.log('CommandOrControl+X is pressed')
})
if (!globalHotkey) {
    console.log('registration failed')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me and suggested ioHook.

https://discuss.atom.io/t/register-strg-as-a-globalshortcut-in-electron/66963/2

```
const ioHook = require('iohook')
// register "STRG+<"   
const id = ioHook.registerShortcut([29, 0], (keys) => {
    console.log('-----------------------------')
    console.log('Shortcut was pressed:', keys)
})
```